# The best way to render conditionally in React from Children to Parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, jsx

I am new to **React** and currently using `react 16.13` and i am trying to figure out how to :

1. pass data from Child to Parent Components
2. when the data is passed if the data is `"true"`, render the Child component in the Parent page.
3. We have two Children, only the one that is `"true"` must be rendered on the Parent page.

```
// Parent

import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ChildOne from './components/ChildOne';
import ChildTwo from './components/ChildTwo';


function App() {
   return (
     <div className="App">
       <ChildOne/>
       <ChildTwo/>
     </div>
   );
}

export default App;

// Component ChildOne

function ChildOne() {
    const isActive = "true";

    return (<div>{isActive}</div>);
}

export default ChildOne;


// component ChildTwo

function ChildTwo() {
    const isActive = "false";

    return (<div>{isActive}</div>);
}

export default ChildTwo;
```

I know this is not the right way to represent the state on each child page but i want to understand how to render the above based on the string value from child to parent so I can refactor the codes using `useState`.

Comment: You really should read React.js documentation.

Comment: Try to ask a specific question based on your own attempts and focus your question to a particular (single) problem. Note that the community here doesn't replace other great online resources such as tutorials. Take at look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to better understand what kind of questions are to be asked on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use callbacks, like events, to send updated data from child to parent. And just handle those callbacks with a function that controls App state.
2. When the component changes it is rendered again, and it render its children again with new props and handlers.
3. You can use a ternary operator to decide which component render.

---

```
function App() {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {isActive
        ? <Child1 isActive={isActive} setIsActive={setIsActive} />
        : <Child2 isActive={isActive} setIsActive={setIsActive} />
     }
    </div>
  );
}

function Child1 ({ isActive, setIsActive }) {
  return (<div onClick={() => setIsActive(!isActive)}>{isActive}</div>);
}

function Child1 ({ isActive, setIsActive }) {
  return (<div onClick={() => setIsActive(!isActive)}>{isActive}</div>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1 pass data from Child to Parent Components**

This is done with callbacks.

**2 when the data is passed if the data is "true", render the Child component in the Parent page.**

Conditional rendering within a Child can be achieved with an if statement in the render method.

```
function ChildOne(props) {
    const isActive =props.isActive;

    return (isActive ?<div>{isActive}</div>:null);
}
```

**3 We have two Children, only the one that is "true" must be rendered on the Parent page.**

If the two children are the same component I would suggest reusing the component. And passing a prop.

```
function Child() {
    const isActive =props.isActive;

    return (isActive ?<div>{isActive}</div>:null);
}



function App() {
   return (
     <div className="App">
       <Child isActive={true}/>
       <Child isActive={false}/>
     </div>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use callback to send data from Child to Parent
2. and 3. You can check the data in parent to render which have data
   is true

```js
// Parent

import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ChildOne from './components/ChildOne';
import ChildTwo from './components/ChildTwo';


function App() {
  const [childData1, setChildData] = useSate(null)
  const [childData2, setChildData] = useSate(null)
  const handleCallBack = (childData) =>{
    setChildData(childData)
    // save or do whatever you want with childData here
  }
   return (
     <div className="App">
       {childData1 === true && <ChildOne callBack={handleCallBack}) data={childData1} />}
       {childData2 && === true <ChildTwo/>}
     </div>
   );
}

export default App;

// Component ChildOne

function ChildOne({callBack, data}) {
    const isActive = "true";

    return (
      <>
      <button onClic={() => callBack(<data you want to sent to parent>)}>Send Data To parent</button>
      </>
      <div>{data}</div>
  )
}

export default ChildOne;


// component ChildTwo

function ChildTwo() {
const isActive = "false";

return (<div>{isActive}</div>);
}
```

  2.